# Django rest framework access related custom fields

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to sum all the `Bars` `progress` value in the `FooSerializer`

The code order is `FooSerializer.get_progress` -> `BarSerializer` , I can't access `BarSerializer.progess` in `FooSerializer`.

```py
from django.db import models
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet


class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=180)

class Bar(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo, related_name='bars', on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class BarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    progress = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_progress(self, instance):
        return 100  # some computed value


class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    bars = BarSerializer(many=True)
    progress = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_progress(self, instance):
        # how to access barSerializer's progress ?
        total = sum(x.progress for x in instance.bars)
        return total
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of definining progress in bar serializer you can set the same method as a property in Bar model .

```
class Bar(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo,related_name='bars',on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    @property
    def progress(self):
        return 100
```

you can specify the progress field in Barserializer's fields.

```
class BarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     class Meta:
           model = Bar 
           fields = '__all__' #specify fields you need in list/tuple(progress will be included in fields).
```

While for Foo serializer you can don't need the progress serializer field

```
class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    bars = BarSerializer(many=True)
```